# Couch DB replication on android device via nodeJs fails

Tags: android, node.js, couchdb, couchbase, couchapp

I have set up a couchdb master server , couch db clinet on android tablet and nodeJs for  the routing. The tablet is able to get data from master initially without any issue. However when I change the data in master, the replication fails with the following message

The same replication works if I remove the nodeJs routing.

```
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014): [error] [<0.999.0>] Worker <0.1008.0> died with reason: {process_died,
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                          <0.1021.0>,
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                          {function_clause,
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                           [{string,tokens1,
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                             [undefined,";",
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                              []]},
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                            {mochiweb_util,
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                             parse_header,1},
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                            {couch_httpd,
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                             get_boundary,1},
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                            {couch_httpd,
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                             parse_multipart_request,
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                             3},
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                            {couch_api_wrap,
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                             '-open_doc_revs/6-fun-1-',
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                             4},
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                            {couch_api_wrap_httpc,
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                             process_stream_response,
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                             5},
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                            {couch_api_wrap,
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                             '-open_doc_revs/6-fun-2-',
02-01 11:59:26.410: E/CouchDB(2014):                                                             4}]}}
02-01 11:59:26.465: E/CouchDB(2014): [error] [<0.999.0>] Replication `d118ca809bc321354f20e94bf000dda1+continuous` (`http://192.168.1.125:5000/mi-master/` -> `flight-oc0001-20120801-ams-sxm`) failed: {worker_died,<0.1008.0>,
02-01 11:59:26.465: E/CouchDB(2014):     {process_died,<0.1021.0>,
02-01 11:59:26.465: E/CouchDB(2014):         {function_clause,
02-01 11:59:26.465: E/CouchDB(2014):             [{string,tokens1,[ ,[]]},
02-01 11:59:26.465: E/CouchDB(2014):              {mochiweb_util,parse_header,1},
02-01 11:59:26.465: E/CouchDB(2014):              {couch_httpd,get_boundary,1},
02-01 11:59:26.465: E/CouchDB(2014):              {couch_httpd,parse_multipart_request,3},
02-01 11:59:26.465: E/CouchDB(2014):              {couch_api_wrap,'-open_doc_revs/6-fun-1-',4},
02-01 11:59:26.465: E/CouchDB(2014):              {couch_api_wrap_httpc,process_stream_response,5},
02-01 11:59:26.465: E/CouchDB(2014):              {couch_api_wrap,'-open_doc_revs/6-fun-2-',4}]}}}
02-01 11:59:26.496: E/CouchDB(2014): [error] [<0.115.0>] Error in replication `d118ca809bc321354f20e94bf000dda1+continuous` (triggered by document `cloud2flight-oc0001-20120801-ams-sxm`): {worker_died,<0.1008.0>,
02-01 11:59:26.496: E/CouchDB(2014):     {process_died,<0.1021.0>,
02-01 11:59:26.496: E/CouchDB(2014):         {function_clause,
02-01 11:59:26.496: E/CouchDB(2014):             [{string,tokens1,[undefined,";",[]]},
02-01 11:59:26.496: E/CouchDB(2014):              {mochiweb_util,parse_header,1},
02-01 11:59:26.496: E/CouchDB(2014):              {couch_httpd,get_boundary,1},
02-01 11:59:26.496: E/CouchDB(2014):              {couch_httpd,parse_multipart_request,3},
02-01 11:59:26.496: E/CouchDB(2014):              {couch_api_wrap,'-open_doc_revs/6-fun-1-',4},
02-01 11:59:26.496: E/CouchDB(2014):              {couch_api_wrap_httpc,process_stream_response,5},
02-01 11:59:26.496: E/CouchDB(2014):              {couch_api_wrap,'-open_doc_revs/6-fun-2-',4}]}}}
02-01 11:59:26.496: E/CouchDB(2014): Restarting replication in 5 seconds.
```

Any help on this

Comment: Why not use Couchbase Mobile or try TouchDB? Also can't you just issue commands over HTTP for replication with Couch? Curious how node fits in?

Comment: If you look for some information about Couchbase mobile join the ml : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mobile-couchbase and take a look to this blog post: http://blog.couchbase.com/get-started-couchbase-mobile

Comment: Thank you for those links. Will surely join the mailing list